# Error with vtkactor in many vtkrenderer

Tags: c++, vtk

about vtkActor has anyone had trouble adding the same actor in more of a "vtkRenderer"

I have three  vtkRenderer in three vtkRenderWindow. 
I add one actor inside three vtkRenderer, but the actor process only the first vtkRenderer.

example:

```
void EstudoMaxilaMandibula::AddPointer(double* p)
{

    vtkSmartPointer<vtkSphereSource> sphereSource = vtkSmartPointer<vtkSphereSource>::New();

    sphereSource->SetCenter(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    sphereSource->SetRadius(2.0);

    vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyDataMapper> mapper = vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyDataMapper>::New();
    mapper->SetInputConnection(sphereSource->GetOutputPort());

    vtkSmartPointer<vtkActor> actor = vtkSmartPointer<vtkActor>::New();
    listActor.push_back(actor);

    actor->SetMapper(mapper);
    actor->SetPosition(p);

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        corte->imageViwer[i]->GetRenderer()->AddActor(actor);
        corte->imageViwer[i]->Render();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please add the text of the error message to the question?

Comment: Sorry, I not get error message. The actor only not visible in the others 2 vtkrenderer.

Comment: Have a look [here](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/Visualization/MultipleActors). It clearly tells you that each actor needs its own mapper. Even if it's the same actor 3 times, you still need mappers to map them to each renderer. Another thing is -> get rid of that `AddViewProp()`, and use `AddActor()` method instead.

Comment: @mutantkeyboard I've moved to addActor. Each player will receive a whole new setting, the only thing that would equal are the vtkrenderers. In this exeplo he explains how each object involved must be configured more does not mention anything about having them in more than one vtkrenderer.

Comment: @JoseBarreto I've just seen your loop. You're fetching imageViewer, but not its RenderWindow(). Try to modify code so it looks like `corte->imageViwer[i]->GetRenderWindow()->GetRenderer()->AddViewProp(actor);` p/s: I'm bit rusty with VTK so forgive me if code doesn't work straight away.

Comment: @mutantkeyboard the problem is in vtk. actors can not be renderers with parents (vtkrenderwindow) different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.

The actors in VTK can not be added in more than one vtkrenderwindow. But they can be added in several vtkrenderer. But these renderes They have to be in the same vtkrenderwindow.

In this post in vtk group has more information.

Making the way I said above, we have something like this:

```
int main(int, char* [])
{
vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindow> renderWindow =
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindow>::New();

vtkSmartPointer<vtkInteractorStyleTrackballActor> style =
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkInteractorStyleTrackballActor>::New();

vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindowInteractor> renderWindowInteractor =
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindowInteractor>::New();

renderWindowInteractor->SetInteractorStyle(style);
renderWindowInteractor->SetRenderWindow(renderWindow);

// Define viewport ranges
double xmins[4] = { 0, .5, 0, .5 };
double xmaxs[4] = { 0.5, 1, 0.5, 1 };
double ymins[4] = { 0, 0, .5, .5 };
double ymaxs[4] = { 0.5, 0.5, 1, 1 };

// Create a sphere
vtkSmartPointer<vtkSphereSource> sphereSource = vtkSmartPointer<vtkSphereSource>::New();
sphereSource->SetCenter(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
sphereSource->SetRadius(5);
sphereSource->Update();

// Create a mapper and actor
vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyDataMapper> mapper = vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyDataMapper>::New();
mapper->SetInputConnection(sphereSource->GetOutputPort());
vtkSmartPointer<vtkActor> actor = vtkSmartPointer<vtkActor>::New();
actor->SetMapper(mapper);

for (unsigned i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderer> renderer = vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderer>::New();

    renderWindow->AddRenderer(renderer);
    renderer->SetViewport(xmins[i], ymins[i], xmaxs[i], ymaxs[i]);

    renderer->AddActor(actor);
    renderer->ResetCamera();

    renderWindow->Render();
    renderWindow->SetWindowName("Multiple ViewPorts");
}

renderWindowInteractor->Start();

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

that way everything works fine.